# Variable initialisation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = {n: 1};
foo.x = foo = {a: 2};
console.log(foo.x);
// Output -- undefined 

var a = 1;
c = b = a;
console.log(a,b,c);
// Output -- 1, 1, 1
```

Could you please explain why first example returns `undefined` where as second returns `1,1,1`?

Comment: `foo` is being reassigned.

Comment: I guess the reason for  this is that Objects are used as reference. So in `foo.x=foo={a:2};`, `foo.x` is assigned something, but then you are changing reference of `foo` itself. So any value set before is lost

Comment: Code works like reading Left to Right, So, `foo.x` is `{a:2}`, but next `foo` becomes `{a:2}`, so it has no `x` property.

Comment: @Rajesh yes Rajesh I thing you are right it was initialised with foo.x = foo first but after that again we are changing foo reference where we don't have x property that's why it returns undefined you are right thanks brother now I got it...

Comment: True `@Rajesh`, Objects are not Primitive, therefore assignment to another variable is a reference to the Object itself, but reassigning a variable will overwrite it anyways.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because expressions in javascript are evaluated left to right.

So in this expression:

```
foo.x=foo={a:2}
```

first the `foo` is dereferenced and a property `x` is set to be the target of the right operand `foo={a:2}` result.

Then, while the right operand is evaluated, the `foo` value is reassigned, so a reference to the previous instance of the object is lost.

To demonstrate it we may simply create another variable to keep it:

```js
var foo = {n:1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x=foo={a:2};
console.log(foo, bar);
```

Comment: You beat me by 17 secs. :-)

Comment: @Rajesh yep, and even variable names matched, sorry ;-)

Comment: Na. I'm glad to delete my answer. Your explanation is way better. :-)

Comment: But still I am having confusion over here if I print bar.x it print {a:2} and foo.x is undefined why is this then if it points to same obj reference then it should print the same value as bar.x

Comment: @ManojSawant see the change, are the results more clear now? "if it points to same obj reference" --- it does not. After the `foo={a:2}` assignment it is a completely new object.

Comment: Oh! now I got it. Foo is now new object that's why foo only has a property and bar has two properties (n,x);

Comment: Got it thank a lot everyone.... this was asked in Barclay's interview I was confused at that time now it is very much clear ...

Comment: That's a really poor interview question, unless the position involves writing the js parsers or interpreters.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the {a:2} object is actually being assigned to the `{n:1}.x` property! Not to `{a:2}`. There is no "x" property in it.

What we have here is:

```
var foo = {n:1};
foo.x = foo = {a:2}; // equals:...
{n:1}.x = {a:2};
/* note that foo.x is actually referring to {n:1} object! */
foo = {a:2}; // ==>
/* while foo is being pointed to a different object
   which is now the {a:2} object!
   wherefore ...*/
{a:2}.x   // is normally undefined i.e.: never set!
```

However:

```
{n:1}.x // has been successfully assigned with:
>> {a:2} object.
```

But because you are loosing a reference to the object {n:1}, and have no other way to examine it. In order to verify and prove that it is {n:1} who is actually receiving the property "x", we'll have to give it a backup  reference before we overwrite the foo variable in order to be able to return it.

```
var foo = {n:1};
var bak = foo;
foo.x=foo={a:2};

console.log(foo.x); 
console.log(bak.x);

>> undefined
>> {a:2}.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foo.x = foo = {a: 2};
```

determines that `foo.x` refers to a property `x` of the `{n: 1}` object, assigns `{n: 2}` to foo, and assigns the new value of `foo` – {n: 2} – to the property x of the {n: 1} object.

The important thing is that the `foo` that `foo.x` refers to is determined before `foo` changes.

The assignment operator associates `right to left`, so you get:

```
foo.x = (foo = {n: 2})
```

The left hand side is evaluated before the right hand side and hence an `undefined` value